# check existing object value in array angular JS

Tags: angularjs

//check from attemptedQues.quesId equals ques

```
      $scope.answer = function (ans, ques, examId) {

      if (logic?) {
        alert("already exixst");
       }
     else {
        attemptedQues.push({ExamId: examId, quesId: ques, ans: ans });
       }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.answer = function (ans, ques, examId) {

      if (attemptedQues.filter(i => i.ExamId === examId).length > 0) {
        alert("already exixst");
       }
     else {
        attemptedQues.push({ExamId: examId, quesId: ques, ans: ans });
       }
};
```

Update: 
If You are not using ES6:

```
$scope.answer = function (ans, ques, examId) {

      if (attemptedQues.filter(function(i) { return i.ExamId === examId}).length > 0 ) {
        alert("already exixst");
       }
     else {
        attemptedQues.push({ExamId: examId, quesId: ques, ans: ans });
       }
};
```

Comment: you can do it with the same function Array.filter, it returns an array of elements, so you can change them as you want, something like this:
var filteredElements = attemptedQues.filter(function(i) { return i.quesId === ques});
for(var i = 0; i < filteredElements.length; i++)
   filteredElements[i].ans = newAns;